# "the tag for an XML node" or "the tag of an XML node" - can both be correct?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wrote :

> The label is used as the tag **for/of?** an Xml node containing this data in the output structure.

I am not sure to use "of" or "for" here. Can both be correct? And in general, when "for" can replace an "of"?

Comment: To my ears this pattern is familiar: use something for doing something else, e. g., you can use water for solving the salt. Or use sth for specific reason. And using sth as sth else. Btw, I think that "of" should be used because you probably want to imply that the tag is associated with the Xml node.

Comment: Is the XmlNode in the output structure? Does "in the output structure" modify "containing" or "node"? or perhaps "data"?

Comment: @TRomano yes, XmlNode is in the output structure and contains this data.

Comment: Your greater challenge is to figure out where to put "in the output structure".   For/of is pretty much even, with **of** winning by a nose.  This label is used as the tag of the XML node that contains the data.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks, first, what is your suggestion for the position of "in the output structure". Second, why you prefer "of the Xml node that contains the data" to "of the Xml node containing the data"?

Comment: I don't see a clear position for that prepositional phrase in the current word order.  I prefer a that-clause because it is a specific node we're talking about (it is the one where the data in question is placed), and a that-clause expresses more clearly than a participle-phrase the idea of a *defining* characteristic.

Comment: The data are placed in an XML node in the output structure and this label is used as the node's tag.

Comment: @TRomano then I should say I don't know when to use which. I thought I can always reduce restricted relative clauses to participle phrases.

Comment: You can use a participle phrase to express a restriction. But to my mind, the *that*-clause expresses the idea more clearly because the "that" is an explicit marker the reduced clause lacks.

Comment: Also, the present tense expresses the idea of an essential feature or core attribute of a particular class more clearly than the participle does: *the animal saying moo* versus *the animal that says moo*.  So it isn't simply a matter of restriction but of class definition.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, `for` is more remote, it is a reference to the XmlNode, but isn't necesarily identical to the index of this node. It may be that `tag` is definatively the index in Xml parlance (I chose to remain ignorant there) but I think the distinction applies regardless.

- The tag `of` a node is probably part of the node.
- The tag `for` a node is probably an external reference to the node.

I think either can be used without seeming unnatural, but you shouldn't assume that this distinction is definitive - even pedantic native speakers might not be consistent here depending on their focus when wtiting. I think the anbiguity comes from the use of `tag` and its potential to be both a simple property and a reference/pointer.

For the non-developers, compare this with how a letter can have an address, and so can a house. The address on the letter points to a house.

Answer (score 1):

*Tag of X* - We are talking about a tag that is part of X.

*Tag for X* - We are talking about an unassigned tag that *could* be used or made part of X, but may not be actually doing that currently.  This also could say that the the tag's purpose is X.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on context. The difference would be one of dependency. Does the tag depend upon the XML node (use *of*), or does the XML node depend upon the tag (use *for*)?

**of**

> 2. (used to indicate derivation, origin, or source):
>      *a man of good family; the plays of Shakespeare; a piece of cake.*

([Of, Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/of?s=t))

**for**

> 2. (intended to belong to, or be used in connection with):
>      *equipment for the army; a closet for dishes.*

([For, Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/for?s=t))

Comment: I can see of and for working in the original sentence, but I don't agree with the depends on context aspect you indicate.

Comment: There's much I'm likely taking for granted as a native English speaker. Could you explain more of why you don't agree - perhaps provide an example of a context in which what I stated doesn't work?

Comment: It might be that your example is too specific, but as a native speaker, I wouldn't describe an alternation between to and for as one of dependency direction.

Comment: The original question was regarding illumination of a technical concept, which ought to entail precision, IMHO. Further, I'm of the not-terribly-informed opinion that English is difficult for non-native speakers in part because of intellectual laziness which has become acceptable use through repetition. At any rate, the definitions of the words _of_ and _for_ certainly imply cardinality of dependency.
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/of?s=t
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/for?s=t

Comment: The name is assigned to the node. It is used as the tag name for the node.

Comment: @Ahmad So, I would say that it's, "The label is used as the tag *of* [...]" (@TRomano's, "This label is used as the tag *of* the XML node that contains the data," is very good.)

Comment: @ThatsNinja You have to be more precise with that link. There are 17 definitions of "of" there none of which use the term "dependency". to/for are sometimes interchangeable and sometimes not. "Love of music" and "love for music" are equivalent. "Love of her father" and "love for her father" are not the same.

Comment: I am a software developer so I am familiar with these technical concepts. English isn't difficult due to intellectual laziness. Language rules are brought about by repeated use.

Comment: @eques I'm accepting that perhaps I'm being intellectually lazy here, or would at least grant that I'm overly focused on the specific question being asked.

Riffing off of the definition above: You can take six pieces _of_ cake and assemble them into a cake-like shape, but what you have are still six pieces which owe their existence to the original, now non-integral cake. They cannot be six pieces _for_ cake.

Conversely, you would purchase flour, eggs, sugar, et cetera _for_ baking that cake. They're not the ingredients _of_ the cake until there's a cake.

Comment: "for" can indicate intended purpose or recipient. "of" can indicate source/origin, composition, etc. There is not one single meaning for either preposition and thus sometimes either is ok and other times only one would fit. To reduce of vs for as dependency direction is really limiting.